# How can I set a matrix with different, repeating patterns in every column?

Tags: arrays, matrix, octave

I'm trying to set an **nx3** matrix in GNU Octave to scatter plot and compare it to a fitted surface which I already solved for and plotted. However this matrix has repeating patterns in columns 1 and 2; I could set them by hand, but the number of rows is somewhat big and the only row I currently have is the non-repeating one (row 3).
For example:

```
A=|1 5 z|
  |2 5 z|
  |3 5 z|
  |4 5 z|
  |1 10 z|
  |2 10 z|
  ...
```

And so on. Where z are the values that I already have as a column vector, which I can simply punch into the matrix with:

```
A(:,3)=z
```

However, I've tried doing

```
A(2:4:n)=2;A(3:4:n)=3;A(4:4:n)=4
```

Which actually worked, for the first column, but had no luck with the second one (and I don't think is the cleanest way to do it). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *seems* to me that the pattern in the first two columns correspond to a grid of coordinates, where `x=1:4` and `y=5:5:20` (or some other end value).

You can generate these coordinates using `meshgrid`:

```
[y, x] = meshgrid(5:5:20, 1:4);
```

(Note how x and y are reversed, don't ask). Next, you can put these into a matrix together with the `z` values you already have as follows:

```
A = [x(:), y(:), z];
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
A(:,1) = x(:);
A(:,2) = y(:);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of the column is repeating in a different way so you can generate each in different ways:

```
octave:1> col1 = repmat ([1:4].', [3 1]); # repeat matrix
octave:2> col2 = ([5 5 5 5].' .* [1 2 3])(:); # automatic broadcasting
octave:3> col3(1:12, 1) = 42; # on the fly by assignment
octave:4> A = [col1 col2 col3]
A =

    1    5   42
    2    5   42
    3    5   42
    4    5   42
    1   10   42
    2   10   42
    3   10   42
    4   10   42
    1   15   42
    2   15   42
    3   15   42
    4   15   42
```